# jQuery UI autocomplete IE issue

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

first my code

```
   $(function() {
        var suggest;
        $("#guestname").keyup(function() {

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: '../include/searchGuest.php',
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: 'searchTxt=' + $(this).val() + '&festival_id=<?php echo $festival_id;?>', 
                success: function(data) {
                    suggest = data;
                    get_autocomplete(suggest);
                }   
            });
        });
    });


    function get_autocomplete(suggest) {
      $("#guestname").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: suggest
      });
    }
```

I use this jQuery function to get a list of guests. The user fills out an inputfield with a name like 'John'. Ajax is searching  a database for guest with either first or lastname containing 'John'. In the same script (PHP) i create a JSON object which looks like ["1234:John Doe","...","..."] (the number is the ID of this guest, guess thats not important, just want to mention that).
Then i pass the JSON to the autocomplete function of jQuery UI.

Everything works fine in FF and Chrome, after getting a result in form of a JSON, a litte window opens below the inputield and shows all matches.
In IE9 its not like it doesnt work at all but i never get the full JSON object as a result. Also, mostly i have to write almost the whole name to get a match - 'Sulliv' to get lastnames like 'Sullivan'. In FF its enough to write 'Sul'.

In the Guest database are aroung 8.1k entries. Can't IE handle a JSON that large or do i have to improve my script. Is it a common issue with IE and JSON or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You should just initialize the autocomplete widget once and then you can use the `source` option to perform the filtering on the server:

```
$("#guestname").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '../include/searchGuest.php',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: 'searchTxt=' + request.term + '&festival_id=<?php echo $festival_id;?>', 
            success: function(data) {
                response(data)
            }   
        });        
    }
});
```

- `request.term` is the term the user searched for.
- `response` is the callback function you must call with autocomplete candidates.

Comment: Atm i use the `keyup` event in the input field. With your code i dont get how i should call the ajax.

Comment: Stupid question is stupid. Forget that one above. It 'works' but my problem with the IE still exists. It's like the IE cant handle the JSON.

Comment: That's odd. Could you limit the results you are returning from the server and see if it still occurs?